# CMMotionManager - getting heading using CMMotionManager exclusively

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cmmotionmanager

I have managed to get compass heading using CLLocationManager but because my app already uses CMMotionManager I would like to measure heading using exclusively CMMotionManager.

Like all Apple vague documentation, you have to guess how to use their APIs.

I have tried to use this to measure heading

```
[self.motionManager setMagnetometerUpdateInterval:1.0/30.0]; //30 Hz

[self.motionManager startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMMagnetometerData *magnetometerData, NSError *error) {
    CMMagneticField compass = magnetometerData.magneticField;
    NSLog(@"x: %f  y:%f  z:%f", compass.x, compass.y, compass.z);
}];
```

the problem is that this block runs just a few seconds then stop running.

Is there any example of how to measure heading using CMMotionManager exclusively?

thanks.

Comment: Are you referencing self.motionManager strongly?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the best way to do it is using CoreLocation, until Apple creates decent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually attempting this, I would recommend using `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` instead of currentQueue. Typically, you only call currentQueue from within an operation to obtain a reference to the queue that started it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you *not* call `start...UpdatesToQueue:withHandler:`. This requires use of a background thread and can be very tricky to manage. You are probably just gunking everything up on the main thread. It's an advanced technique, and you don't need it.

Instead, just `start` and then use an NSTimer or similar to poll the CMMotionManager repeatedly.