# How to use performSelector on block

Tags: ios, block, performselector

Below is the code :

```
if ([motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 100.0;
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(exchangeCard)
                               withObject:nil
                               afterDelay:0];

    }];
```

I found the selector was not been called on the block. So my question is how to make the performSelector to call the function on block

Comment: Why are you using `performSelector` instead of just calling the method?

Comment: What do you mean "called on the block"? Is `exhangeCard` being called? Is `performSelector:` being called? - Are you aware that you shouldn't really be using `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue` unless you understand threading?

Comment: the above code looks fine. Are you sure that the block is executing?

Comment: And as @MarceloFabri said, why don't you just call `[self exchangeCard]` from within the block?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818527/cmmotionmanager-getting-heading-using-cmmotionmanager-exclusively

Comment: Yes, I understand that it could use [self exchangecard] to solve this problem. But the point is why performSelector could not use on block and how to use it on block. Because I encounter a problem that the function will use some private class that will use performSelector to do somethings. So the codes just are the discription. @matt

Answer (score 2):

There is usually no need to use `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:`, and you certainly shouldn't use it unless you know what you're doing with threading. It doesn't look to me as if you do! The way to use the motion manager is to start it, and then just repeatedly *ask* it for updates (you can set that up with a repeating NSTimer).

```
self.motman = [CMMotionManager new];
if (!self.motman.accelerometerAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"oh well");
    return;
}
self.motman.accelerometerUpdateInterval = // whatever
[self.motman startAccelerometerUpdates];
NSTimeInterval t = self.motman.accelerometerUpdateInterval * 10;
self.timer =
    [NSTimer
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:t
        target:self selector:@selector(poll:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

So now `poll:` will be called repeatedly and you can do whatever you want:

```
- (void) poll: (id) dummy {
    // ask self.motman for current values here; for example:
    CMAccelerometerData* dat = self.motman.accelerometerData;
    // now do something with that info
}
```

For actual code and a full explanation of how to use the motion manager to get acceleration values, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_raw_acceleration

Comment: deviceMotionUpdateInterval is not "whatever" - `the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds`.

Comment: No, @AndreiG., read the docs. The update interval is one thing; the timer is another. That is *another* good reason for polling. The motion manager will stay up to date at *its* interval; you just pick up info as often as *you* need to.

Comment: agreed, it's just your code is using `accelerometerUpdateInterval` for setting `NSTimer` delay (Ex: if I set `accelerometerUpdateInterval` to 0.01 - NSTimer will be running outside of it's recommended frequency range), IMO it is best to make these two independent of each other, and hard-code `NSTimer` delay to as frequent as you need to poll. Other then this, all is peachy, Cheers :)

Comment: My timer is ten times slower than the motion manager update interval, and in any case the OP can of course use any values that suit.